# How to remove the page number(s) of one section (and its subsections) from ToC of article document?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I want to remove page numbers of the last section and its subsections from an article document's table of contents. I have gone through several questions and answers about this topic and ended up breaking my document. Luckily I had a previous version of my thesis saved in the morning. At the moment I have

```
Section ............ 1
  subsection ....... 2
Section ............ 4
  subsection ....... 6
Section ............ 8
  subsection ....... 9
```

in my table of contents and I want

```
Section ............ 1
  subsection ....... 2
Section ............ 4
  subsection ....... 6
Section 
  subsection
```

instead. All the help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package for controlling the ToC (and LoF and LoT).

```
% sectocprob.tex  SE 623057

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{B subsection}
%% add into the ToC
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{sec}} % no section page numbers 
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{subsec}} % no subsection page numbers
\section{Third section}
\subsection{C subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks reasonably simple. However, my TexStudio says `'package not found'` after installling `tocloft` (Windows PC).

Comment: @Jonne Then you have a problem with your installation. The `tocloft` package is included within the TeXLive distribution.

Comment: Now it works. I restarted TexStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not numbering the section or subsection in the table of contents, I assumed you are adding them using `\addcontentline`

So you need to do 2 things for the last section and subsection

1. suppress the page number, and
2. delete the dots.

If you are using the `book` class remove `\renewcommand*\l@section{...`

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}

% adds dots for section in class article
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{0.5em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
    
\clearpage
\section*{First}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{First}
\subsection*{First subsec}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{First sub}

\section*{Second}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Second}
\subsection*{Second subsec}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Second sub}

% supress page numbers => https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9294/161015
\renewcommand*{\addcontentsline}[3]{\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{}}}
% supress the dots => https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71329/161015
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\string\@dotsep{100}}
\makeatother
        
\section*{Third}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Third}
\subsection*{Second subsec}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Third sub}    
\subsection*{Third sub}
    
\end{document}
```

**NOTE**
If this solution doesn't work for you, it may be because you are using another class and additional packages that modify the table of contents. If this is the case, post a minimal compilable example with its full preamble. (from  `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`)